# Get positional information from one object and apply it to another

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to query the location of an object (x,y,z coordinates) with xform, and then set the values harvested from xform to use in a setAttr command to influence the translation of a different object.

```
pos = cmds.xform('pSphere1', r=True, ws=True, q=True, t=True )
print(pos)
cmds.setAttr('pSphere2', tx=pos[0], ty=pos[1], tz=pos[2])
```

The print command is providing me with the correct coordinates however the setAttr command isn't picking them up and using them.

I'm getting the error:

Error: TypeError: file  line 1: Invalid flag 'tx'

Is this something to do with the 'data type' of the **xform** being "linear" and the **setAttr** being something else? If so, how do I work around or convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use it like that :

```
    cmds.setAttr('pSphere2.tx', pos[0])
```

and your query should be

```
    pos = cmds.xform('pSphere1', ws=True, q=True, t=True )
```

To apply you can also do

```
    cmds.xform('pSphere2', ws=True, t=pos )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something which is also possible with those commands :

```
pos = cmds.xform('pSphere1', ws=True, q=True, t=True)
cmds.setAttr('pSphere2.t', *pos)
```